# How can I pull my code from github on to my vs code/computer?

Tags: visual-studio, github, command, clone

I've had quite a lot of files this year and not enough space so I had to delete some things. However, I need to edit some of those files. I have the repo I need on my github, I just don't know the command or how to pull it on to my vscode to edit. Can anyone give me the steps on what to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways you can do this.

1. git clone your repo to your local computer and open that folder with VScode
2. Install extension where you can clone your repo using vscode.

VScode is an ide so you should be able to open any folder with it.